# How to write that the only integers that have a multiplicative inverse are $1$ and $-1$, in symbolic form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, proof-explanation, symbolic-computation

Could it be something like for $(1,-1) \in \mathbb{Z}$, there exists $y \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $xy = 1$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}^\ast = \{\pm 1\}$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)

Comment: You have said that $\pm 1$ have inverses, not that those are the only integers with inverses.  You should also use braces for a set and $\subset$, not $\in$.

Answer (score 1):

For any (unital) ring $R$, the set of units $R^\times$ is the group consisting of
$$
\{ x \in R \mid \exists\, y \in R \text{ s.t. } xy = 1 \}. 
$$

Your (true) claim that the only units in the integers could be written:
$$
\{ x \in \mathbb{Z} \mid \exists\, y \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ s.t. } xy = 1 \} 
= \{ -1, +1 \} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

The units in $\mathbb Z$ are $1,-1$. (Units are just invertable elements in a group).

More formally from wikipedia, a unit of a ring $\displaystyle R$R is any element $\displaystyle u\in R$$\displaystyle u\in R$ that has a multiplicative inverse in $\displaystyle R$R: an element $\displaystyle v\in R$ $\displaystyle v\in R$ such that

$\displaystyle vu=uv=1$$\displaystyle vu=uv=1$, where 1 is the multiplicative identity.

So using this definition, it is quite obvious that the units in $\mathbb Z$ are $1,-1$.
(I hope this helped? I am known not to explain things the best).

Comment: Hi! I don't need to prove that the only units are 1 and -1, but instead, write in symbolic form the above statement.

Comment: I understand, but I don't understand. One could simply just use the definition of unit and do some simple computation, and end with the results $1,-1$. Or maybe you could go for contradiction; i.e., assume that there are units other than $1,-1$ or assume that $1,-1$ are not units? I don't know. Because symbolically, this is simple. Just notice that $1,-1$ obey the following axioms for a unit, and you can symbolically obtain this result.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen $U(R)$ for the group of units in a ring R (I mean it is a group iff the ring contains a unit, so it is not a group if your ring is $2\mathbb{Z}$). I think I have also seen $R^{\times}$. I think the latter is probably the more common one.

Comment: Do you intend to write $R^\times$ because *that* is a common notation.

Comment: Yes, fixed. Thanks for pointing that out.